# Linting error: Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement

Tags: angular, lint

Could you please help to fix linting error with below javascript function.

Error: Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement.

```
  item.EmployeeDetails = item.EmployeeDetails
                            .sort((a: IEmployeeDetails, b: IEmployeeDetails) => {
        if (a.employeeType < b.employeeType) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.employeeType > b.employeeType) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

sort() mutates the array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods

So, try to omit the assignment operator:

```
item.EmployeeDetails.sort((a: IEmployeeDetails, b: IEmployeeDetails) => {
    if (a.employeeType < b.employeeType) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.employeeType > b.employeeType) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I will check this and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 6):

In order to resolve this, you have to copy the original array before sorting. This is because sorting using .sort() mutates the original array. You can read more about this linting error here: https://rules.sonarsource.com/typescript/RSPEC-4043

```
const sortedEmployeeDetails = [...item.EmployeeDetails]
                                .sort((a: IEmployeeDetails, b: IEmployeeDetails) => {
            if (a.employeeType < b.employeeType) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a.employeeType > b.employeeType) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const empDetail = Object.assign(item, {});

 return empDetail['EmployeeDetails '].sort( (a: any , b: any) => {
    if (a.employeeType < b.employeeType) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.employeeType > b.employeeType) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

}

Comment: simply assign empdetail in new object & then perform sorting , it might not make lint issues

Comment: Can you please know me which kind lint error you are getting

Comment: please check know with adding return statement before assigning

Comment: I could find sth similar thing here with no solution - https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/blob/master/sonarts-core/tests/rules/noMisleadingArrayReverseRule/noMisleadingArrayReverseRule.lint.ts

Comment: Set item object as public & then use with this statement.might it helps